# I need an explanation for assembly code

Tags: assembly

Can someone please explain this piece of assembly code to me?It's simple but i have no idea what's going on.

```
code_segment segment

assume cs:code_segment

mov ah, 01h
int 21h   
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h   
code_segment ends
end


code_segment segment
assume cs:code_segment
repeat: mov ah, 01h
int 21h  
jmp repeat
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h 
code_segment ends
end
```

Comment: Why not simply read your notes? If you don't have any, why haven't you took any note? Did your professor give you any slide, reference text? Have you tried [Googling your troubles](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm)? What about hiring a private tutor if you don't feel like studying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do actually have two programs and not one. Each `code_segment segment ... code_segment ends` denotes one. Which one will be executed depends on the entry point of the [*PE header*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable), because there is no reference/call/jump/interaction between them.

So the first code snippet just does read a character using the [DOS-interrupt 21h, function 01h - Read char](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm) and then exits the program using the [DOS-interrupt 21h, function 4Ch - Exit program](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm).

The second code snippet is erroneous. It is an infinite loop reading chars with [DOS-interrupt 21h, function 01h - Read char](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm) and will never proceed beyond the `JMP`, because there does not exist an 'exit' condition/instruction.

Comment: Thank you. You guys really saved me.

Answer (score 0):

`int`denotes an interrupt. Your example use the following interrupts:

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
```

is used to read a character on standard input

```
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
```

is used to exit the application.

[source](https://www.csc.depauw.edu/~bhoward/asmtut/asmtut12.html)